# Knot complement conjecture in solid tori

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Has the knot complement conjecture been proven for knots in solid tori?

Comment: What does the conjecture say?Do you have a link where it is discussed? Adding context to your question makes it better, because it makes it useful to people who are not you!

Comment: I suspect the conjecture is that a knot is determined by topology of its complement. This is a famous theorem of Gordon and Luecke for knots in the 3-sphere.

Answer (score 2):

If the conjecture is what I think it is (i.e. knots are determined by their compliments), then not, at least when knots are considered up to isotopy. A solid torus is an exterior of the unknot, so take a Whitehead link and twist around one of the components. The exterior of this link stays the same, and it is the exterior of the second component in the solid torus. But the second component changes (because you are performing meridional twists in the solid torus), and in fact the second component becomes a different knot (more or less) each time you twist, so these different knots cannot be isotopic in the solid torus (as they are not isotopic in $S^3$). I don't know the answer if you consider knots up to homeomorphism. But surely the answer factors through the corresponding question for two-component links with one component an unknot.

Comment: Yes you have the right conjecture, and I do mean up to isotopy.  You say "the second component becomes a different knot (more or less)".  If the isotopy is $\phi$, and the space is $T^2 = S^1XD^2$ then I mean that $\phi$ would be fixed on the boundary, $S^1XS^1$. Sorry for not making that last part clear, I know how important it is to be clear in asking these questions.

Comment: Fixing the isotopy on the boundary is not really a problem: it is a constraint, even without which this still works. In other words, even without fixing the boundary, you cannot isotope one of these knots to another one, so a fortiori you cannot isotope them fixing the boundary.

Comment: Either your meridional twist will not fix the boundary in the isotopy, or the isotopy will not change the link in the way you want.  Imagine the solid torus embedded in $R^3$ and that the isotopy is fixing the boundary and the complement of $T^2$ as well. Your method couldn't work here, because of the knot complement conjecture. Right?

Comment: You are right in saying that the meridional twist changes the knot - but that's the point! Meridional twist is a homeomorphism, and it shows, that the complements of the different knots (in the solid torus) you get are the same (meaning homeomorphic). But the knots are different (meaning not ambient isotopic).

Comment: Thank you for your time. Although your statement about the homeomorphism is true, it isn't true in the context of an isotopy, which is what I am interested in.  The question is "up to isotopies which fix the boundary of the solid torus, are knots determined by their complements?".  In other words if there is an isotopy of the knots, is there an isotopy of the complement of the knots (that fixes the boundary)? Again, I apologize for not making this clear.  I am new to this yet.

Comment: I think that what you are asking now in your comment is not usually understood as "being determined by the complement", because the definition of knots involves ambient isotopy, i.e. isotopy of the whole space, so this is true simply by definition (and you shouldn't worry too much about fixing the boundary, this can always be done for any isotopy, because the boundary is collared).

Comment: Your counterexample is a link (not a knot).  Perhaps if I restrict the conjecture to "if the complements of two prime knots in the solid torus are homeomorphic then the two knots are isotopic in the solid torus" could be true.  If this is true then it could prove a conjecture about embeddings of $R^1$ in $D^2 X R^1$,

Comment: The counterexample I gave you is a knot in a solid torus, and solid torus is the exterior of an unknot, so the exterior of the knots I give in the counterexample are also the exterior of a certain link (Whitehead link). So these are knots (not links) in the solid torus. I am not sure how primeness comes into play here, but I am not even sure how to define connected sums for knots in solid tori, so let alone I don't know what it means for such knots to be prime.

Comment: What you say is correct.  A picture would have helped me see it. If I have it right now, any meridian of the solid torus would bound a disk which would transversely intersect the knot in two points.  I would imagine that a connected sum would be performed inside a ball whose sphere boundary intersects the knot in two points, in which case the knot you refer to would be prime anyway.  I thought that perhaps the "cutting disks" which are so hard to define in the proof that Gordan and Lucke gave, would be easy to define in a solid torus, but I was wrong.  Thank you for your helpful comments.